# PHP artisan serve failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

It is the first time that I did run the laravel server using the command:

> php artisan serve

This is what I get:

```
HP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  require(/home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/example-app/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/example-app/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/example-app/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php8:/usr/share/php/PEAR') in /home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/example-app/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/julian/Documentos/Programacion/LARAVEL/example-app/artisan on line 18
```

So I run the command:

> composer update

And this is the console ouput

```
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0 Loading composer repositories with package information Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine Updating dependencies Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php8/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/ctype.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/curl.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/dom.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/gd.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/iconv.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/intl.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/openssl.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/pdo.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/phar.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/xsl.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/zip.ini
    - /etc/php8/conf.d/zlib.ini You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode. Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

the same output with **composer install** command.

The PHP version is 8.1.10
Composer version 2.4.1

I also delete the ; from the sentences of /etc/php8/cli/php.ini file.

extension=curl
extension=fileinfo

What I must is works with the composer command and adds **--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo** But Why I should ignore it? it's because I'm using php8 and laravel should works with php7?

Comment: how is the value of php on composer.json ? does it have a ^ or ~ ?

Comment: it's 8.0.2 and I change it to  8.1.10 but i get the same ouput

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, as there isn't really enough info, just can't comment yet...

If you have PHP8.1, looks like you could possibly be using PHP 8 within nginx or apache when serving your laravel project

Also, may have to update your league/mime-type-detection package, as it looks like the requirement is for PHP7, but the updated version seems to PHP 7 or PHP 8 as a requirement

For the `fileinfo` plugin, maybe try installing with `sudo apt install php{version}-common`